# Lofoten Islands by rental car (one way)

Tags: car-rentals, norway

We plan to get a rental car, see Lofoten for 3-4 days, and deliver the car further south in Norway.

1. What is the best place to pick up the car, cost and experience vise?
2. How can we minimize the cost of different pickup and drop-off location?

Coming by plane to Bodø (can extend )

Comment: http://www.avis-lofoten.com

Comment: If you know the area you know its not really a price question, also I am not asking for a particular agency.  National rental companies would normally work through a local garage - it is not so convenient for them to have cars ending up at other companies or receive cars which are not theirs.  Also with small stations is not so easy to match rentals in one direction with rental in the opposite direction.  Bodø is relatively large, but there is water between there and Lofoten.   There is also the cost of flying all the way, and the issue where it is best to start experience vise.

Comment: I will post another question consentrating on the experience, and then looking at the cost later.